# PostgreSQL Bloat Warning: Vaccuum does not help

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

We use check_postgres to monitor our DB. We get this warning:

```
POSTGRES_BLOAT WARNING: 
DB "foo" (db foo) index foo_text_index_id_uniq rows:? 
pages:485435 shouldbe:330673 (1.5X) wasted bytes:1267810304 (1 GB)
```

According to the [docs](https://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#bloat) a vacuum should help, but the autovacuum does not help.

What can I do to get rid of the bloat?

Comment: Is it causing anything bad?  If you have a working autovacuum setup, the table should not grow much.

Comment: Do you have any sessions that are "idle in transaction"? Open transactions that have touched that table will prevent (auto)vacuum to clean up properly.

Comment: I think you should raise your critical values as 1.5X is a fairly reasonnable value concerning bloat. On my side, I use 2X.

Comment: @dezso good question: No, it does not do any harm. But I want to get our monitoring logs clean. For me clean is binary: it is clean or not. That's why I want to solve this. OK, an other solution would be to stop doing this test .... :-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, not there are no idle session.

Answer (score 1):

Vacuuming will not remove the existing bloat.  It will free up that space for future use.  Until that future use has happened, it will still look bloated.

To free it up **now**, you would have to do something drastic like `VACUUM FULL`, `CLUSTER`, or use some external tool like [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack).  That is a lot of churn to put your database through just to fix a problem that is not actually a problem.

I would just do as @KookieMonster said, and increase the threshold.  Then if things start to get worse, eventually you will start getting warnings again.  (Actually, I wouldn't run check_postgres in the first place, but if I were, then...see above.)

Comment: you don't use check_postgres. Interesting. Don't you monitor your db? I guess you do. How do you do it?

Comment: @guettli  In addition to being the DBA, I'm also a power "end-user" of my database.  So if there are performance problems, I experience them firsthand and learn about them that way.  I am also constantly forking the database, both to get a fresh test/dev environment, and to have confidence in the backup/restore procedures.  So if it were getting bloated for space I would notice the problem through that avenue.  I don't recommend that other people avoid `check_postgres`, I just never felt the need myself.